# Trying to give the user an option to choose category in hangman

Tags: javascript, html

These are the categories for which I have made the arrays in JavaScript

```
var f1teams = [
    ["F","E", "R", "R", "A", "R", "I"],
    ["M", "C", "L","A","R","E","N"]
    ["R","E","D","B","U","L","L"],
    ["S","A","U","B","E","R"],
    ["F","O","R","C","E","I","N","D","I","A"],
    ["R","E","N","A","U","L","T"]
] 

var PremierLeague = [
    ["L","I","V","E", "R", "P", "O", "O", "L"],
    ["L", "E", "I","C","E","S","T","E","R"]
    ["A","R","S","E","N","A","L"],
    ["M","A","N","C","H","E","S","T","E","R","C","I","T","Y"],
]
```

This is the html `dropdown` menu I made to choose category linking to `setCategory` function `onChange` event.

```
<select id ="cards" onchange="setCategory()">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Please select a Category</option>
    <option value = "PL">Premier League Football Teams</option>
    <option value = "F1">Formula 1 Teams</option>
</select>
```

This is the setCategory function giving a default value of f1teams. I call `setUnderline()` at the end of the function,to set the blanks accordingly

```
var selectCat = f1teams.slice();

function setCategory() {
    var e = document.getElementById("cards");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (strUser == "F1") {
        window.alert("You have chosen Formula1 as your category");
        selectCat = f1teams.slice();
    }
    else if (strUser == "PL") {
        window.alert("You have chosen Premier League as your category");
        selectCat = PremierLeague.slice();
    }
    else {
        window.alert("Please choose a category");
        selectCat = f1teams.slice();
    }
    setUnderline();
}
```

These are some variables defined outside any function followed by the setUnderline function and the initiation.

```
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * (selectCat.length))); 
var letter = selectCat[random];
var underline = new Array(letter.length);

for (var i = 0; i < underline.length; i++){
    underline[i] = "_ ";
}

function setUnderline(){
    for (var i = 0; i < underline.length; i++){
        var guessfield = document.getElementById("guessfield");
        var letters = document.createTextNode(underline[i]);
        guessfield.appendChild(letters);
    }
}

function initiation(){
    if (selectCat !== null) {
        setUnderline();
    }
    window.onload = initiation;
```

However when I click on the `dropdown` menu to change the category it just forms some new blanks of the same word.

Before changing:

[image]

After changing:

[image]

How can I make it so that it will make blanks for a different word in a different category instead of just forming the blanks for the same word on changing category.

My whole code is uploaded here on [this repo](https://github.com/zakomon/Hangman-fossasia) but without the setCategory() function

[Live Demo](http://cdn.rawgit.com/zakomon/Hangman-fossasia/master/main.html)

Comment: It's great the you added the repo link, however it will be better if you will add a snippet or bin **with** the problem so we could see the problem and try to debug it.

Comment: @MoshFeu Here is a link to the page live cdn.rawgit.com/zakomon/Hangman-fossasia/master/main.html ignore the go button and poor design

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're on the right track.

It looks to me as though you're missing out the step where you delete the contents of the `guessfield` element.

Such a step might look something like this:

```
function setUnderline() {
  var guessfield = document.getElementById("guessfield");

  // Clear the existing contents of guessfield
  guessfield.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < underline.length; i++){
    var letters = document.createTextNode(underline[i]);
    guessfield.appendChild(letters);
  }
}
```